# Creating a new OpenSSL EC Point using prime256v1 and a known public key

Tags: ruby, openssl

I'm trying to turn a known public key into an instance of `OpenSSL::PKey::EC::Point` with the following code:

```
require 'base64'
require 'openssl'

public = 'MDkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDIgAD5tgZhw82GpGYJYkWNgeDp/0OzT4y/YLS+tMpZeJ2VEQ='

decoded_public = Base64.encode64(public)
hex_string = decoded_public.each_byte.map { |b| b.to_s(16) }.join()

ec_group = OpenSSL::PKey::EC::Group.new('prime256v1')
key = OpenSSL::PKey::EC.new(ec_group)
bn = OpenSSL::BN.new(hex_string, 16)
point = OpenSSL::PKey::EC::Point.new(ec_group, bn)
```

The error occurs on the last line, throwing:

```
`initialize': invalid encoding (OpenSSL::PKey::EC::Point::Error)
```

I run `Base64.encode64` and then turn each byte into a hex representation because from reading around it seems like hex strings are a common way of creating a new BigNum.

I'm guessing it is something I'm doing wrong with the public key information, because the `ec_group` gets created without complaint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, that string is already base64 encoded, so you need to *de*code it, not *en*code it:

```
decoded_public = Base64.decode64(public)
```

The result you get is a DER encoded structure containing the key, so trying to look at the bytes directly isn’t going to get you anywhere (you can see what it contains using `OpenSSL::ASN1.decode(decoded_public)`).

You can however use [`OpenSSL::PKey::read`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.3/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/PKey.html#method-c-read) directly on `decoded_public`, which will give you an `OpenSSL::PKey::EC` object (with the correct group). To get the associated point you can just call [`public_key`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.3/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/PKey/EC.html#method-i-public_key):

```
key = OpenSSL::PKey.read decoded_public
point = key.public_key
```

The result is an `OpenSSL::PKey::EC::Point` object.

Comment: Thanks, the en/decode was a typo. I didn't know about being able to read directly though!